# Checking Activity lifecycle state outside an Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

Is it any way to check Activity lifecycle state outside an Activity? It is easy to achieve maybe, but I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: what you want to do ?

Comment: Store a reference in application level.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14470360/5545429 see this

Comment: @ShinilMS your answer helped me, thank you. I haven't thought about callbacks...

Comment: Happy to help! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can put a static method and variable in the Activity, then in the `onPause`, `onCreate`, `onResume` you can modify the variable. From other activities you can call the variable to know the activity state.

Activity1:

```
public static int state = 0;
...
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
Activity1.state = 1;
...
}

@Override
    protected void onPause()
    ...
    Activity1.state = 2;
    ...
}

@Override
    protected void onResume() {
    ...
    Activity1.state = 3;
    ...
}
```

Then you can check for the state in other activities like:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    int state = Activity1.state;
    Toast.makeText(this,"Activity1 state is "+state, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    ... 
}
```

...Hope it helps

Comment: Yes, it's a kind of solution, but I want to avoid static fields :D Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the activity state in Shared preference and use it whenever and wherever you want.