# Can I use to Firebase FrameMetricsAggregator to monitor ad activities within my game?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-performance

Recently my game has shown considerable rise in frozen frames on android vitals after introduction of ads.

I want to use FrameMetricsAggregator for monitoring which ad activities are causing this issue(app rendering is based on open gl apart from ads).

I added monitoring in my code as per documentation but the results are always null if i dont specify any activity in the construtor. Since ad show calls are void return types , im not sure how to monitor those specific activities.

Any ideas about how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yaay found something to help my self,

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11082332/6053599

Using the code in the above answer I can get lifecycle callbacks of ad activities ``which can be used to start and stop the trace and frame metrics.

This works like this,

When the ad is shown a new activity created and we are notified by `onActivityCreated(activity,bundle)` callback, add the activity recieved in the callback into frame metrics by calling `frameMetrics.add(activity)`

After that when ad is closed we are notified by `onActivityStop(activity)` in which simply call `frameMetrics.stop()` to get the sparseArray of frame stats from which i can count the janky frames , frozen frames etc.

Will update the answer with final code if anybody is interested.