# How to distinguish a running app, background app and turned off app while being inside the service

Tags: android, react-native

Let's say I'm inside a `BroadcastReceiver` class that handles push notification.

How can I check if the application, this service is running for, is in the **Foreground**, in the **Background** or is completely **turned off**?

Comment: You can check this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks.html but not entirely sure if it meets your requirement https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10606408/automatically-log-android-lifecycle-events-using-activitylifecyclecallbacks

Answer (score 0):

You can just call `AppState` API from react-native core (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appstate.html) and get this information.

If you are using `react-native-push-notification` module, when you receive a notification, you also receive a boolean that indicates if the app is on foreground mode or not.

https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification