# How to call API when app state become foreground from background in android MVVM structure

Tags: android, mvvm

Call API when app state become foreground from background in MVVM structure in android platform.

Comment: use `onStart` or `onResume` (depending on the usecase) to trigger a method on your ViewModel. https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle

Comment: @Blundell I have 5 different screen and I want to trigger same API for every screen when app comes to foreground after background.

Comment: If you have 1 activity, then you have 1 callback

Answer (score 0):

You can use registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks to follow up the lifecycle of your app.

For example usage: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14470360/5686866

Comment: How to get access of repository or viewmodel inside lifecycle class. I want to implement using MVVM structure.

Comment: I don't know your project structure but maybe you can use dependency injection to pass your viewmodel to lifecycle class then use it